# Sum of squares complex numbers in descending order

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I would like to calculate the sum of squares complex numbers in descending order by using three source codes(Complex2.h, Complex2.cpp, Vector3)
ex) (5+6i)^2 (3+4i)^2 (1+2i)^2....

I'm trying to add and change some codes in Vector3 to get the result, but stuck in the middle now..
Does anyone give some advice?

```
//Complex2.h
#ifndef  COMPLEX2_H_INCLUDED
#define  COMPLEX2_H_INCLUDED
#include    <ostream>
using namespace std;
class  Complex2 {
    double  rPart, iPart;           // real part and imaginary part
public:
    // operator
    Complex2(double r = 0, double i = 0) : rPart(r), iPart(i) {}
    Complex2  conj()  const {
        return Complex2(rPart, -iPart);
    }
    Complex2  operator+(const Complex2 &c) const;
    Complex2  operator+(double r) const;
    Complex2  operator-(const Complex2 &c) const;
    Complex2  operator-(double r) const;
    Complex2  operator*(const Complex2 &c) const;
    Complex2  operator*(double r) const;
    Complex2  operator/(const Complex2 &c) const;
    Complex2  operator/(double r) const;
    Complex2& operator+=(const Complex2 &c);
    Complex2& operator-=(const Complex2 &c);
    Complex2& operator*=(const Complex2 &c);
    Complex2& operator/=(const Complex2 &c);
    bool      operator==(const Complex2 &c) const;
    bool      operator!=(const Complex2 &c) const;
    double    real() const { return rPart; }
    double    imag() const { return iPart; }
    void  display() const;      // print complex value
    friend  Complex2  operator+(double r, const Complex2& c);
    friend  ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex2& c);
};
#endif

//Complex2.cpp
#include    <iostream>
#include    "Complex2.h"
using namespace std;

Complex2 Complex2::operator+(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart + c.rPart, iPart + c.iPart);
}    

Complex2 Complex2::operator+(double r) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart + r, iPart);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator-(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart - c.rPart, iPart - c.iPart);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator-(double r) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart - r, iPart);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator*(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart * c.rPart - iPart * c.iPart, rPart * c.iPart + iPart * c.rPart);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator*(double r) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart * r, iPart * r);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator/(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    double  d = c.rPart * c.rPart + c.iPart * c.iPart;
    return Complex2((rPart * c.rPart + iPart * c.iPart) / d, (iPart * c.rPart - rPart * c.iPart) /     d);
}

Complex2 Complex2::operator/(double r) const
{
    return Complex2(rPart / r, iPart / r);
}

Complex2& Complex2::operator+=(const Complex2 &c)
{
    rPart += c.rPart;    iPart += c.iPart;
    return *this;
}

Complex2& Complex2::operator-=(const Complex2 &c)
{
    rPart -= c.rPart;    iPart -= c.iPart;
    return *this;
}

Complex2& Complex2::operator*=(const Complex2 &c)
{
    *this = *this * c;
    return *this;
}

Complex2& Complex2::operator/=(const Complex2 &c)
{
    *this = *this / c;
    return *this;
}

bool Complex2::operator==(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return  rPart == c.rPart && iPart == c.iPart;
}

bool Complex2::operator!=(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return  rPart != c.rPart || iPart != c.iPart;
}

void  Complex2::display() const
{
    cout << "(" << rPart;
    if (iPart > 0)
        cout << "+j" << iPart;
    else if (iPart < 0)
        cout << "-j" << -iPart;
    cout << ")";
}    

Complex2  operator+(double r, const Complex2& c)
{
    return Complex2(r + c.rPart, c.iPart);
}

ostream&  operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex2& c)
{
    os << "(" << c.rPart;   // print real part
    if (c.iPart > 0)        // print imaginary part
        os << "+j" << c.iPart;
    else if (c.iPart < 0)
        os << "-j" << -c.iPart;
    cout << ")";
    return os;
}    

//Vector3.cpp
#include  <iostream>
#include  <vector>
#include  <cstdlib>
#include  <ctime>
#include  <algorithm>
#include "Complex2.h";
using  namespace  std;

template<typename T> struct GREATER {
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
        return a > b;
    }
};

int  main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));   // Initialize random number generation

    vector<Complex2> cv1(5);
    cout << "vector1 : ";
    for (auto &c : cv1) {
        c = rand() % 100;         // 0~99 random number generation
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    sort(cv1.begin(), cv1.end(), GREATER<int>());   // sort algorithm in descending
    cout << endl << "sorted vector1 : ";
    for (auto c : cv1)
        cout << c << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    vector<Complex2> cv2(5);
    cout << "vector2 : ";
    for (auto &c : cv2) {
        c = rand() % 100;         // 0~99 random number generation
        cout << c << " ";
    }
    sort(cv2.begin(), cv2.end(), GREATER<int>());   // sort algorithm in descending
    cout << endl << "sorted vector2 : ";
    for (auto c : cv2)
        cout << c << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    // vector for saving the merged result
    vector<Complex2> cv3(cv1.size() + cv2.size());
    // Save the result cv1 plus cv2 as cv3
    merge(cv1.begin(), cv1.end(),
        cv2.begin(), cv2.end(), cv3.begin(), GREATER<int>());
    cout << "the result of merged vector1 and vector2 : ";
    for (auto c : cv3)
        cout << c << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sort(cv1.begin(), cv1.end(), GREATER<int>());` That doesn't make sense. You take a comparator that knows how to compare `int`s, and try to use it to compare complex numbers. Mathematically, complex numbers don't form a single total order, so it's not clear what it means to sort them.

Comment: The problem statement mentions "sum of squares", but the code shown doesn't sum or square any numbers, complex or otherwise.

Comment: You can replace `GREATER` with `std::greater`

Answer (score 1):

To do this, all you actually need is to define `operator>`:

```cpp
bool Complex2::operator>(const Complex2 &c) const
{
    return rPart * rPart + iPart * iPart > c.rPart * c.rPart + c.iPart * c.iPart;
}
```

Then you can call `std::sort` and `std::merge` with:

```
std::sort(cv1.begin(), cv1.end(), std::greater<Complex2>());

std::merge(cv1.begin(), cv1.end(), cv2.begin(), cv2.end(), 
           cv3.begin(), std::greater<Complex2>());
```

Side note: why not use `std::complex`?

Comment: That will work, on the assumption the OP meant "magnitude" when they wrote "square".

Comment: @dxiv Actually if you square a complex number, the magnitude of it is also squared, unless I'm totally off today

Comment: Right, and because of that comparing the squares of the magnitudes gives the same sort order as comparing the magnitudes themselves. But the OP wrote just "squares", and it is not possible to compare the "squares" because the square of a complex number is itself a complex number and there exists [no total order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers) for complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which is very important here:

**It is impossible to order complex numbers!!!**

You are talking about ordering them, and you seem to be looking for some ordering function, but you need to know that, whatever the means of ordering complex numbers, the ordering must satisfy following argument:

```
Order(Number1, Number2) AND Order(Number2, Number3) => Order(Number1, Number3)
```

This expression can't be true, for any kind of ordering you might be inventing (at least for complex numbers, for real numbers ordering is simple), so your question about "descending order" of complex numbers cannot make sense.

The whole explanation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers).

Comment: We can create a strict weak ordering, which is all we need to sort. Whether it is mathematically useful is another matter.